# xcopy with unc path adds virtual network drives

Tags: scripting, batch-file, dos

When i copy files to a some network path with xcopy command I get new virtual drives on my pc .
The problem is that i do that within a batch script that runs in scheduler so i get there a lot of drives to same location.

How I can copy files to a network with out getting a new drives on the pc or just remove them 
?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait a minute. You're using `pushd`. `pushd`, as the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490978.aspx) states:

> If Command Extensions are enabled the
>   PUSHD command accepts network paths in
>   addition to the normal drive letter
>   and path. If a network path is
>   specified, PUSHD will create a
>   temporary drive letter that points to
>   that specified network resource and
>   then change the current drive and
>   directory, using the newly defined
>   drive letter.  Temporary drive letters
>   are allocated from Z: on down, using
>   the first unused drive letter found.

While that's perfectly fine to use, you should never call `pushd` without an appropriate `popd` afterwards.

So instead of just

```
pushd \\somepath\etc
xcopy "%mycopyposition%*.exe"
```

you add another line

```
popd
```

which will de-allocate the temporary drive letter again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the command you are using to call xcopy. Can we see that ?

Comment: i call it via batch file 
first i do 
pushd \\somepath\etc
then i do 
xcopy "%mycopyposition%\*.exe"

Answer (score 0):

the `net` command is your fiend (as good a fiend you can get on Windows). To remove a network drive you might want to look at:

```
net use /?
```

Comment: Is it possible somehow not to get all that network drives  via the commands i run to get them ? i use pushd and xcopy . thanks